# Agile Web Development with rails 4 - Checkout - line items invalid

Tags: ruby-on-rails

[image]I am learning ruby on rails following the book agile development. Last thing I did, I created the Checkout part: [image] I added the action to the controller, and the method for the instance variables of the model. Everything is working as expected, ... to a certain degree.

When I insert the values for name, address, emailaddress and pay type and stuff, I receive an error-notification saying "Item not valid".

Some validation test might be written wrong. Anyone having an idea what could be wrong?

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :line_items, dependent: :destroy
PAYMENT_TYPES = [ "Check", "Credit Card", "Purchase order"]
validates :name, :address, :email, presence: true
validates :pay_type, inclusion: PAYMENT_TYPES
 def add_line_items_from_cart(cart)
  cart.line_items.each do |item|
   item.cart_id = nil
  line_items << item
end
end
end
```

Controller

```
  def new
  if @cart.line_items.empty?
  redirect_to store_url, notice: "Your cart is empty"
  return
end

  @order = Order.new
end

 # GET /orders/1/edit
def edit
end

 # POST /orders
# POST /orders.json
def create
  @order = Order.new(order_params)
  @order.add_line_items_from_cart(@cart)

  respond_to do |format|
  if @order.save
    Cart.destroy(session[:cart_id])
    session[:cart_id] = nil

    format.html { redirect_to store_url, notice: 'Thank you for your order.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @order }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @order.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
  end
 end
```

fixtures

```
 one:
  product_id: ruby
  cart_id: one

 two:
  product_id: ruby
 cart_id: one
```

Here is my github account 
https://github.com/KerstinKee/depot

Comment: `Line items is invalid` suggests that there's a validation error with the line items referenced by this order. Also according to the [Rails API docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates), `validates :pay_type, inclusion: { in: PAYMENT_TYPES }}` should be the correct syntax for the validation of the payment methods.

Comment: infact there is something wrong with the line items: If I hit the "Add to cart" Button for the first time, it does not show up the value for the price, but if I click the "Add to Cart" Button a second time, it shows up a the value for the price, also if I hit the "Att to Cart" Button for the third and fourth time. Maybe it is related to that issue... I added a screenshot. It does not count the first line item

Answer (score 0):

You have two validations. If you really pass name, address and email, then second validation fails.

```
validates :pay_type, inclusion: PAYMENT_TYPES
```

What pay_type do you choose?

You can get validation errors via:

```
object.errors.messages
```

Good luck!

Comment: Hi Stanislav, thanks for your comment: Unfortunately, I do not get it. I choose "check" as payment method. I guess I have to rewrite the validations ...

Answer (score 0):

I would look at the code for adding a product to the cart, the validations look correct, the model defines the business rules, relationships between the objects (each object defined by a controller has a table (row) in the database).

If a part of your code deletes an object (table row) before another object (table row entry) is saved this will break the relationship in the databse which appears as a validation error as well, in my case, I was executing a charge within its own rescue block after the order save command (the first part of this deletes the cart object), the stripe charge lines of code were dictating when the order was saved which was after the lines of code in which the order was saved, this caused the error "invalid line items", once the charge code was put before @order.save and within a single begin rescue block the orders saved without error [link][rails 4 stripe payment causing line item invalid error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30442434/rails-4-stripe-payment-causing-line-item-invalid-error/307973)