# rails 4 stripe payment causing line item invalid error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, stripe-payments

Like others working with Stripe payments, I was getting an error 'Cannot charge a customer that has no active card'.  The form was not appending the token because the javascript did not have a matching id in the form, but now I am getting an rails error and the card is not being charged, the customer is created, the error states that there is an invalid line item, when the code to create the customer and charge the card is not run the order is created without error.

Order View

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.stripe.com/v2/">

$(function(){

  Stripe.setPublishableKey('<%= Rails.configuration.stripe[:PUBLISHABLE_KEY] %>');

});

</script>

<div class = "Power Me" >

  <fieldset>

    <legend> Please enter your details </legend>

    <%= render 'form', object: @object %>

  </fieldset>

</div>
```

Rendered Order Form

```
<%= form_for(@order, :html => {:id => 'payment-form'}) do |f| %>

  <% if @order.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@order.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this order from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @order.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">

    <%= "Order Total: #{order_total.to_s}" %>
    <%= "Order Currency: #{order_currency.to_s}" %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :Address_line_1 %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :address_line_1 %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :Address_Line_2 %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :address_line_2 %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :City %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :address_city %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :Region %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :address_state %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :Postcode %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :address_zip %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :Country %><br>
    <%= f.select :address_country, Order::CC_COUNTRIES, prompt: 'Select the country' %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :email, :placeholder => "you@example.com" %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :Payment_Type %><br>
    <%= f.select :pay_type, Order::PAYMENT_TYPES, prompt: 'Select a payment method' %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-row">
        <label>Card Number</label>
        <input type="text" size="20" autocomplete="off" data-stripe="number" id="number" class="credit-number", placeholder = "**** **** **** ****" pattern="[\d ]*" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-row">
        <label>Security Code/CVC</label>
        <input type="text" size="4" autocomplete="off" data-stripe="cvc" id="cvc" class="credit-scurity" placeholder="***" pattern="\d*" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-row">
        <label>Expiration (MM/YYYY)</label>
        <input type="text" size="2" data-stripe="exp-month" id="exp-month" class="card-expiry-month" placeholder="MM" pattern="\d*" />
        <span> / </span>
        <input type="text" size="4" data-stripe="exp-year" id="exp-year" class="card-expiry-year" placeholder="YYYY" pattern="\d*" />
    </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit 'Pay', :class =>"stripe-button" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

orders model

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base

#  attr_accessor :stripeToken

  PAYMENT_TYPES = ["credit card"]

  CC_COUNTRIES = ["United Kingdom", "France", "Italy"]

  validates :name, :address_line_1, :address_zip, :email, presence: true

#  validates :pay_type, inclusion: PAYMENT_TYPES

  has_many :line_items, dependent: :destroy

  def add_line_items_from_cart(cart)

    cart.line_items.each do |item|

      item.cart_id = nil

      line_items << item

    end

  end
end
```

Orders Controller

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController

  include CurrentCart

  before_action :set_cart, only: [:new, :create]

  before_action :set_order, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /orders
  # GET /orders.json
  def index
    @orders = Order.all
  end

  # GET /orders/1
  # GET /orders/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /orders/new
  def new

    if @cart.line_items.empty?

      redirect_to store_url, notice: "Your cart is empty"

      return

    end

    @order = Order.new

  end

  # GET /orders/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /orders
  # POST /orders.json
  def create

    @order = Order.new(order_params)

    @order.add_line_items_from_cart(@cart)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @order.save

        Cart.destroy(session[:cart_id])

        session[:cart_id] = nil

        format.html { redirect_to @order, notice: 'Order was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @order }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @order.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end

    Stripe.api_key = "sk_test_BsdqHq0SQuPqHIsm46lcpX4v"

    @amount = order_total.to_i * 100

    token = params[:stripeToken]
=begin
    begin

      customer = Stripe::Customer.create(

        :email => order_params[:email]

      )

      charge = Stripe::Charge.create(

        :customer    => customer.id,
        :amount => @amount, # amount in cents, again
        :currency => order_currency,
        :card => token,
        :description => order_params[:email]
      )

      redirect_to root_path

    rescue Stripe::CardError => e

      @error = e

    end
=end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /orders/1
  # PATCH/PUT /orders/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @order.update(order_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @order, notice: 'Order was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @order.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /orders/1
  # DELETE /orders/1.json
  def destroy
    @order.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to orders_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_order
      @order = Order.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def order_params
      params.require(:order).permit(:name, :email, :pay_type, :address_line_1, :address_line_2, :address_city, :address_state, :address_zip, :address_country)
    end
end
```

My Application Helper

```
module ApplicationHelper

      def order_total

        total = LineItem.joins(:product).select("sum(line_items.quantity * products.price) as total").where("cart_id = ?", session[:cart_id]).first.total

      end

      def order_currency

        currency = LineItem.joins(:product).joins(:currency).select("currencies.name as iso_name").where("cart_id = ?", session[:cart_id]).first.iso_name

      end


      # Returns the full title on a per-page basis.
      def full_title(page_title)
        base_title = "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"
        if page_title.empty?
          base_title
        else
          "#{base_title} | #{page_title}"
        end
      end

      def bootstrap_class_for flash_type

        { success: "alert-success", error: "alert-danger", alert: "alert-warning", notice: "alert-info" }[flash_type] || flash_type.to_s

      end

      def flash_messages(opts = {})

        flash.each do |msg_type, message|

          concat(content_tag(:div, message, class: "alert #{bootstrap_class_for(msg_type)} fade in") do

            concat message
         end)

        end

          nil

      end

      # before filters

      def signed_in_user

        unless signed_in?

          store_location

          redirect_to signin_url, notice: "Please sign in."

        end

      end

      def correct_user

        @user = User.find(params[:id])

        redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user?(@user)

      end

      def admin_user

        redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user.admin?

      end

end
```

Orders.js

```
$('#payment-form').submit(function(event) {

  var form = $(this);

  form.find('button').prop('disabled', true);

  Stripe.createToken(form, stripeResponseHandler);

  return false;

});
```

Comment: I'd ensure that stripeToken is actually being set and not equal to null. Your current code should be throwing an error of "Customer cus_XXXXXXX does not have a card with id tok_YYYYYYYYYYY"

Comment: thanks, that was part of the problem

Answer (score 0):

Working Order Form below, you cannot pass fields to Stripe and use them in the rails form to save in the db, its either or (previous example attempted to save address fields in the db and pass them to stripe as part of the transaction validation.

```
<%= form_for(@order, :html => {:id => 'payment-form'}) do |f| %>

  <% if @order.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@order.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this order from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @order.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">

    <%= "Order Total: #{order_total.to_s}" %>
    <%= "Order Currency: #{order_currency.to_s}" %>

  </div>

  <div class="form-row">
        <label>Full Name</label>
        <input type="text" size="20" autocomplete="off" data-stripe="name" />
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :email, :placeholder => "you@example.com" %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :Payment_Type %><br>
    <%= f.select :pay_type, Order::PAYMENT_TYPES, prompt: 'Select a payment method', :selected => "credit card" %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-row">
        <label>Address Line 1</label>
        <input type="text" size="20" autocomplete="off" data-stripe="address_line1" />
    </div>

  <div class="form-row">
        <label>Address Line 2</label>
        <input type="text" size="20" autocomplete="off" />
    </div>

  <div class="form-row">
        <label>Address City</label>
        <input type="text" size="20" autocomplete="off" />
    </div>
  <div class="form-row">
        <label>Address State</label>
        <input type="text" size="20" autocomplete="off" />
    </div>


  <div class="form-row">
        <label>Zip/Postcode</label>
        <input type="text" size="20" autocomplete="off" data-stripe="address_zip" />
    </div>



  <div class="form-row">
        <label>Country</label>
        <input type="text" size="20" autocomplete="off" data-stripe="address_country" />
    </div>
  <div class="form-row">
        <label>Card Number</label>
        <input type="text" size="20" autocomplete="off" data-stripe="number" placeholder = "**** **** **** ****" pattern="[\d ]*" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-row">
        <label>Security Code/CVC</label>
        <input type="text" size="4" autocomplete="off" data-stripe="cvc" placeholder="***" pattern="\d*" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-row">
        <label>Expiration (MM/YYYY)</label>
        <input type="text" size="2" data-stripe="exp-month" placeholder="MM" pattern="\d*" />
        <span> / </span>
        <input type="text" size="4" data-stripe="exp-year" placeholder="YYYY" pattern="\d*" />
    </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit 'Pay', :class => "button" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

The form required the id referenced inthe javascript below

```
var stripeResponseHandler = function(status, response) {
  var $form = $('#payment-form');

  if (response.error) {
    // Show the errors on the form
    $form.find('.payment-errors').text(response.error.message);
    $form.find('button').prop('disabled', false);
  } else {
    // token contains id, last4, and card type
    var token = response.id;
    // Insert the token into the form so it gets submitted to the server
    $form.append($('<input type="hidden" name="stripeToken" />').val(token));
    // and re-submit
    $form.get(0).submit();
  }
};


jQuery(function($) {

  $('#payment-form').submit(function(e) {
  var $form = $(this);

  // Disable the submit button to prevent repeated clicks
  $form.find('button').prop('disabled', true);

  Stripe.card.createToken($form, stripeResponseHandler);

  // Prevent the form from submitting with the default action
  return false;
  });
});
```

Order Model, fields removed

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base

  PAYMENT_TYPES = ["credit card"]

  CC_COUNTRIES = ["United Kingdom", "France", "Italy"]

  validates :email, presence: true

  validates :pay_type, inclusion: PAYMENT_TYPES

  has_many :line_items, dependent: :destroy

  def add_line_items_from_cart(cart)

    cart.line_items.each do |item|

      item.cart_id = nil

      line_items << item

    end

  end
end
```

Application header

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all",
                                           "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.stripe.com/v2/"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

      $(function(){

        Stripe.setPublishableKey('<%= Rails.configuration.stripe[:publishable_key] %>');

      });

    </script>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= render 'layouts/shim' %>
  </head>
  <body>
```

Order Controller

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController

  include CurrentCart

  before_action :set_cart, only: [:new, :create]

  before_action :set_order, only: [:show,:edit, :update, :destroy]

#  before_action :admin_user, only: [:destroy, :show]


  # GET /orders
  # GET /orders.json
  def index
    @orders = Order.all
  end

  # GET /orders/1
  # GET /orders/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /orders/new
  def new

    if @cart.line_items.empty?

      redirect_to store_url, notice: "Your cart is empty"

      return

    end

    @order = Order.new

  end

  # GET /orders/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /orders
  # POST /orders.json
  def create

    begin

      @order = Order.new(order_params)

      @order.add_line_items_from_cart(@cart)

      Stripe.api_key = "sk_test_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

      @amount = order_total.to_i * 100

      token = params[:stripeToken]

      # Create a Customer
      customer = Stripe::Customer.create(

        :description => order_params[:email], 
        :card => token, 

      )


      charge = Stripe::Charge.create(

        :customer    => customer.id,
        :amount => @amount, # amount in cents, again
        :currency => order_currency,
       # :card => token,
        :description => order_params[:email]
      )

      respond_to do |format|

        if @order.save

          puts "saving now"

          Cart.destroy(session[:cart_id])

          session[:cart_id] = nil

          format.html { redirect_to @order, notice: 'Order was successfully created.' }
          format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @order }
        else
          format.html { render action: 'new' }
          format.json { render json: @order.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
      end

      rescue Stripe::CardError => e

      flash[:error] = e.message
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /orders/1
  # PATCH/PUT /orders/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @order.update(order_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @order, notice: 'Order was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @order.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /orders/1
  # DELETE /orders/1.json
  def destroy
    @order.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to orders_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_order

      @order = Order.find(params[:id])

    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def order_params

      params.require(:order).permit(:email, :pay_type)

    end
end
```